# Rails / Devise: Set session and cookies without creating a User?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

I want to **create a session** and **set cookies** for that session-instance.

Especially in order to **associate different anonymous requests to a browser** (or to multiple browsers on one machine each, respectively) and in order to **be able to be GDPR compliant.**

There is basically no need to create an instance of a `User` model for this. It would suffice to keep track of the sessions in, say, `ActiveRecord::SessionStore`.

The [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/SessionStore.html) says that a database table is necessary in order to keep track of the sessions obviously.

Devise doesn't provide the possibility to create bare Sessions, right?

So I have to resort to `ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session` and `ActiveRecord::SessionStore` to create bare sessions... (?)

Would it be viable to use both Rails and Devise sessions? Rails sessions for anonymous requests as stated above and Devise sessions for logged in users. *I don't see the conflict here.*

If it weren't for the fact that both Devise sessions and Rails sessions of the current request are both available through a `session[]`-Hash.

**I don't know, if I create a name-collision, when I begin to use Rails Sessions with Devise Sessions for logged-in users.**

So much,
I appreciate every answer.

Von Spotz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `devise` gem is designed to work with a `User` model and assumes there will be a record in that table.  What I think you want is to not authenticate with devise as far as devise knows.

To use devise, somewhere you have something like this:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

in your controllers.  You need to simply not include this in the controllers where you want to skip the devise authentication.  If this is in the base `ApplicationController` then you might use `skip_before_action` or only use the `before_action` above in those controllers where you want authentication.

The session is managed by rails and not devise.  (Actually it is managed by the rack layer.)  So you won't have any problems using the session hash and it will be unique for the session.

Comment: Thanks. Spot on answer.

Comment: May I ask you, as you seem knowledgable with devise, where the difference is between using an `authenticated :user do` block in `config/routes.rb` and using `before_action :authenticate!` in `UsersController`? I will eventually make the question an own thread. Thanks. So long.

Comment: I don't know but I might guess there is no difference.